# Natural Flavor, Natural Flavors, and Natural Flavoring

Tags: is-it-vegan

Products that list "natural flavor" as an ingredient (deceitfully, IMO) rarely if ever inform consumers that "natural flavor" is usually -- not always -- an animal byproduct. I've resorted to emailing companies to request information on this additive, and some will tell you that it's an animal-sourced additive, and others will say that theirs is plant-based. Some just ignore the annoying hippie. But we also see "natural flavors" (plural instead of singular) and "natural flavoring".
My question is twofold:
First, is there a difference between these three ingredients and
Second, is there a good, up-to-date list of companies whose "natural flavor" is known and trusted to be plant-based?
I searched this website for "natural flavor" but didn't get much success. I should also say that I'm mostly dealing with US labeling.